# Export from JSON file the coordinates

Tags: javascript, geojson

I can't export and print the coordinates, the format of JSON is came from a query in a database the format is:

> {"st_asgeojson":"{\"type\":\"LineString\",\"coordinates\":[[23.4582348,37.5062675],[23.4577141,37.5066109],[23.4572601,37.5070038],[23.4566746,37.507301],[23.455698,37.5076256],[23.4549737,37.5079214],[23.4545445,37.5080235],[23.4538579,37.5078873],[23.4531713,37.5077852],[23.4521842,37.5078533],[23.4513688,37.5079895],[23.4324646,37.5234265],[23.4324646,37.5236308],[23.4326363,37.5237669]]}"}

I try this code but I have not take anything:

`JSON.parse(JSON.parse(jArray).st_asgeojson).coordinates.forEach(function(entry) {
        flightPlanCoordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(entry[1],entry[0]));
    });`

I want to take the coordinates for example

> 23.4582348,37.5062675
>   23.4577141,37.5066109
>   23.4572601,37.5070038

Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try parsing the JSON like this:

```
var json = {
    "st_asgeojson": {
        "type":"LineString",
        "coordinates":[
            [23.4582348,37.5062675],
            [23.4577141,37.5066109],
            [23.4572601,37.5070038],
            [23.4566746,37.507301],
            [23.455698,37.5076256],
            [23.4549737,37.5079214],
            [23.4545445,37.5080235],
            [23.4538579,37.5078873],
            [23.4531713,37.5077852],
            [23.4521842,37.5078533],
            [23.4513688,37.5079895],
            [23.4324646,37.5234265],
            [23.4324646,37.5236308],
            [23.4326363,37.5237669]
        ]
    }
}

var coords = json.st_asgeojson.coordinates;

coords.forEach(function(entry){
        flightPlanCoordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(entry[1],entry[0]));
});
```

Here's a real simple [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bse3r8fb/) to show the parse works.